# Maximum flow and cyclic partitions

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

The digraph $ G = (V, E)$ is called cyclic if $\exists  k ≥ 1$
circuits in $ G, C_1, . . . , C_k,$ whose set of vertices, $V (C_1), . . . , V (C_k),$ forms a partition of $V (G)$. Prove that you can test in polinomial time (in relation to $|V | + |E|$) if the digraph $ G = (V, E)$ is cyclic by solving the maximum flow problem in a network of flows conveniently constructed.

I know this problem is not strictly mathematical but I will be grateful for any pointers or indications.

Comment: This question seems to be related with the flow decomposition theorem.
see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370052/eliminating-cyclic-flows-from-a-graph